# List Find() throws Null Exception but should give an empty string

Tags: c#

In C#, I have a List that has a fixed number of items, 6 to be precise. These are called out in a Razor template, by using a Find(). However, if that Find cannot find the associated list item, it throws a NullReference exception.

The problem is, if an item doesn't exist, then the view won't load.

I need it to instead provide an empty string to the variable.

I've tried:

```
var video1 = Model.Videos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VideoType == "Video1") ?? string.Empty;
```

But this still returns null.

Could anybody help in getting this to work?

Comment: Model or Videos is null

Comment: Clue: what's the default value of a string? It's not an empty string. Or Model or Videos could be null.

Comment: I don't even know how that compiles.... `Videos` is obviously a complex class, yet somehow you are null coalescing to a string?

Comment: @TyCobb, because he used a `var`. One of the egregious reasons not to use `var`.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Negative. It's figured out at compile time, not at runtime. `var` is safe and awesome. =)

Comment: @TyCobb. You are correct, but that is the reason it 'compiles'. Don't get me wrong, I use `var` all the time. I also try to make sure it's obvious what `var` should be.

Comment: @TyCobb would it not simply take the type `object`?

Comment: @JamesMonger No, it should be creating the error below. It's not `var`, changing it `object` should still cause the issue. CS0019 -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63h61ky.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the null-propagation operator as described in [**C# : The New and Improved C# 6.0**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

An example of usage would be:

`var video1 = Model?.Videos?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VideoType == "Video1") ?? string.Empty;`

The above will ensure that no `NullReferenceException` will be thrown when `Model` or `Videos` are `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing a `NullReferenceException` because you are trying to get a property/call a function on a `null` object.

Looking at your code, we are calling `Videos` on `Model`, and then calling `FirstOrDefault` on `Videos`.

A `NullReferenceException` being thrown means that either:

- `Model` is null, so when you call `Model.Videos` you get a `NullReferenceException` (because you cannot get the property `Videos` of null)
- `Videos` is null, so when you call `Videos.FirstOrDefault` you get a `NullReferenceException` (because you cannot call the function `FirstOrDefault` on null.